# fgetc null terminator

Tags: c, fgetc, null-character

I'm doing an exercise in K&R:

> Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop.

And this is what I have so far (w/o error checking on the file):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define tab 2
#define MAX_LENGTH 1000
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");    
    int c, n;
    char buffer[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
    for (n = 0; n < MAX_LENGTH && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; ++n) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            for (int x = 0; x < tab; ++x)
                buffer[n++] = ' ';
            --n;
        }
        else
            buffer[n] = c;
    }
    //buffer[n] = '\0';
    //rewind(fp);
    //fputs(buffer, fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work, but I'm wondering why `\0` wasn't needed at the end. Was I just lucky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you were lucky. To avoid this problem, you could have used `fwrite`, which doesn't require a null terminator (since you specify exactly how many bytes to write):

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, n, stdout);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can tell [`printf(...)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) the (maximum) number of characters to print for a given string.

```
printf("%.*s\n", n, buffer);
```

See [printf(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html), section "The precision":

> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.')  followed by an optional
>     decimal digit string.  Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" 
>     [...] to specify that the precision is given in
>     the next argument [...], which must be of type int. [...]
>     This gives [...] the maximum number of characters to be printed from a
>     string for s [...] conversions.

Live demo of `printf ("%.*s\n", 5, "Hello, world!")`: http://ideone.com/KHKLl.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize your buffer with:

```
memset(buffer, '\0', MAX_LENGTH + 1);
```

And you wont have to worry about the null termination.

Comment: He won't overrun the buffer in this case - the position in the buffer (`n`) is checked to be less than `MAX_LENGTH`. In his code, `MAX_LENGTH` is the maximum output length, not input.

Comment: Ah good point, for some reason I "saw" he was using another variable in the for.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, you were lucky that the array contained nulls at the right places.

You can initialise it when you create it using this shorthand:

```
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = { 0 }; // all elements will be zero
```

Note that this is because the compiler will initialise unspecified entries with zeroes - so if you said

```
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH + 1] = { 'a' };
```

then the array would be `{'a',0,0,0....}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I never noticed {0} set all elements to be zero only because unspecified entries will be initialized to zero.